# How to add demo content in avada wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to create wordpress site's blog page which can be directly done by  adding demo content of avada wordpress theme that i know but i don't know how actually it can be possible. so please guide me about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

login to the wp-admin > appearance > go to the theme option > general tab > click on Import demo content button and you will get the demo content added in the avada theme